# How can I show which tables, schemas, and queries my snowflake users are running?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

As a part of implementing my data governance and security policies, I want a query that will summarize which tables and queries users are running within our snowflake data warehouse. However, for some reason the query I've written below is showing the same counts across a wide variety of table and database names in a way that is not possible, but I don't know what I am doing wrong. Can someone help me?

```
with BASE_TABLE AS
(
select 
DISTINCT
q.query_id,q.user_name, 
t.table_catalog||'.'||t.table_schema||'.'||t.table_name as TABLE_NAME, 
date(q.start_time) as start_time, 
date(q.end_time) as end_time, 
q.query_text, 
q.QUERY_HASH,
q.TRANSACTION_ID AS TRANSACTION_ID, 
q.QUERY_TYPE, q.DATABASE_NAME,
q.total_elapsed_time, 
q.error_message, 
q.rows_produced
from SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.QUERY_HISTORY q

inner join SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.SCHEMATA s
on s.schema_id = q.schema_id
inner join SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.tables t
on t.Table_Catalog_Id = s.catalog_id
where
q.QUERY_TYPE IN ('SELECT') AND (DATEDIFF('day', q.start_time, CURRENT_DATE()) < 10) AND USER_NAME = CURRENT_USER()
order by start_time

)

SELECT
HASH(USER_NAME) as HASHED_USERNAME,
HASH(TABLE_NAME) AS HASHED_TABLE,
HASH(DATABASE_NAME) AS HASHED_DATABASE,
SUM(TOTAL_ELAPSED_TIME) AS TOTAL_ELAPSED_TIME, 
COUNT(DISTINCT QUERY_ID) AS COUNT_DISTINCT_QUERIES,
COUNT(QUERY_ID) AS COUNT_QUERIES,
COUNT(DISTINCT TRANSACTION_ID) AS COUNT_TRANSACTIONS,
COUNT(TRANSACTION_ID) AS COUNT_DISTINCT_TRANSACTIONS,
COUNT(DISTINCT QUERY_HASH) AS COUNT_TRANSACTIONS,
COUNT(QUERY_HASH) AS COUNT_DISTINCT_TRANSACTIONS


FROM
BASE_TABLE
GROUP BY
HASH(USER_NAME),
HASH(TABLE_NAME),
HASH(DATABASE_NAME)
ORDER BY 

COUNT_QUERIES DESC
```

Here are the results

| HASHED_USERNAME | HASHED_TABLE | HASHED_DATABASE | TOTAL_ELAPSED_TIME | COUNT_DISTINCT_QUERIES | COUNT_QUERIES | COUNT_TRANSACTIONS | COUNT_DISTINCT_TRANSACTIONS | COUNT_TRANSACTIONS | COUNT_DISTINCT_TRANSACTIONS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3887381369861525738 | 1945340309824620743 | 898887959080212926 | 535644 | 21 | 21 | 1 | 21 | 21 | 21 |
| 3887381369861525738 | -4616442389233058623 | 898887959080212926 | 535644 | 21 | 21 | 1 | 21 | 21 | 21 |
| 3887381369861525738 | -4212540120345798750 | 898887959080212926 | 535644 | 21 | 21 | 1 | 21 | 21 | 21 |
| 3887381369861525738 | 5980557708429672617 | 898887959080212926 | 535644 | 21 | 21 | 1 | 21 | 21 | 21 |
| 3887381369861525738 | 3369788839536702744 | 898887959080212926 | 535644 | 21 | 21 | 1 | 21 | 21 | 21 |
| 3887381369861525738 | 3103805130751933993 | 898887959080212926 | 535644 | 21 | 21 | 1 | 21 | 21 | 21 |
| 3887381369861525738 | 3369194188630188473 | 898887959080212926 | 535644 | 21 | 21 | 1 | 21 | 21 | 21 |
| 3887381369861525738 | -1388130469552469802 | 898887959080212926 | 535644 | 21 | 21 | 1 | 21 | 21 | 21 |
| 3887381369861525738 | 5296998886063006138 | 898887959080212926 | 535644 | 21 | 21 | 1 | 21 | 21 | 21 |
| 3887381369861525738 | -1205276443672336873 | 898887959080212926 | 535644 | 21 | 21 | 1 | 21 | 21 | 21 |
| 3887381369861525738 | 6953418390285744175 | 898887959080212926 | 535644 | 21 | 21 | 1 | 21 | 21 | 21 |
| 3887381369861525738 | -3599077089501770287 | 898887959080212926 | 535644 | 21 | 21 | 1 | 21 | 21 | 21 |
| 3887381369861525738 | 8718371642347779580 | 898887959080212926 | 535644 | 21 | 21 | 1 | 21 | 21 | 21 |
| 3887381369861525738 | 7387734859250322094 | 898887959080212926 | 535644 | 21 | 21 | 1 | 21 | 21 | 21 |
| 3887381369861525738 | 3557755812202779741 | 898887959080212926 | 535644 | 21 | 21 | 1 | 21 | 21 | 21 |
| 3887381369861525738 | 1165314329380729482 | 898887959080212926 | 535644 | 21 | 21 | 1 | 21 | 21 | 21 |
| 3887381369861525738 | -7990670065733459633 | 898887959080212926 | 535644 | 21 | 21 | 1 | 21 | 21 | 21 |
| 3887381369861525738 | -4685577508027201512 | 898887959080212926 | 535644 | 21 | 21 | 1 | 21 | 21 | 21 |
| 3887381369861525738 | -8371413216131909451 | 898887959080212926 | 535644 | 21 | 21 | 1 | 21 | 21 | 21 |
| 3887381369861525738 | -7871497817898561830 | 898887959080212926 | 535644 | 21 | 21 | 1 | 21 | 21 | 21 |
| 3887381369861525738 | 2078952832918936688 | 898887959080212926 | 535644 | 21 | 21 | 1 | 21 | 21 | 21 |
| 3887381369861525738 | -8585785269086934496 | 898887959080212926 | 535644 | 21 | 21 | 1 | 21 | 21 | 21 |
| 3887381369861525738 | -8384312141715502044 | 898887959080212926 | 535644 | 21 | 21 | 1 | 21 | 21 | 21 |
| 3887381369861525738 | 852611112587303935 | 898887959080212926 | 535644 | 21 | 21 | 1 | 21 | 21 | 21 |
| 3887381369861525738 | -4483963476942413267 | -5548156286948121666 | 5031 | 14 | 14 | 1 | 14 | 11 | 14 |
| 3887381369861525738 | 7114757706702089035 | -5548156286948121666 | 5031 | 14 | 14 | 1 | 14 | 11 | 14 |
| 3887381369861525738 | -3250339579281137906 | -5548156286948121666 | 5031 | 14 | 14 | 1 | 14 | 11 | 14 |
| 3887381369861525738 | -4029039986611889666 | -5548156286948121666 | 5031 | 14 | 14 | 1 | 14 | 11 | 14 |
| 3887381369861525738 | 2213942325610079716 | -5548156286948121666 | 5031 | 14 | 14 | 1 | 14 | 11 | 14 |
| 3887381369861525738 | -9066226388484550429 | -5548156286948121666 | 5031 | 14 | 14 | 1 | 14 | 11 | 14 |
| 3887381369861525738 | 3727724902188989294 | -5548156286948121666 | 5031 | 14 | 14 | 1 | 14 | 11 | 14 |
| 3887381369861525738 | -4934948697580836438 | -5548156286948121666 | 5031 | 14 | 14 | 1 | 14 | 11 | 14 |
| 3887381369861525738 | -371732026850655487 | -5548156286948121666 | 5031 | 14 | 14 | 1 | 14 | 11 | 14 |
| 3887381369861525738 | -8842918132270421096 | -5548156286948121666 | 5031 | 14 | 14 | 1 | 14 | 11 | 14 |
| 3887381369861525738 | -90912629732873415 | -5548156286948121666 | 5031 | 14 | 14 | 1 | 14 | 11 | 14 |
| 3887381369861525738 | -3956469106837040872 | 8065311635230324086 | 14990 | 6 | 6 | 1 | 6 | 5 | 6 |
| 3887381369861525738 | -1636296315423719518 | 8065311635230324086 | 14990 | 6 | 6 | 1 | 6 | 5 | 6 |
| 3887381369861525738 | -7130098365051457219 | 8065311635230324086 | 14990 | 6 | 6 | 1 | 6 | 5 | 6 |
| 3887381369861525738 | 5296998886063006138 | 2250074648582266096 | 1403 | 6 | 6 | 1 | 6 | 6 | 6 |
| 3887381369861525738 | -8384312141715502044 | 2250074648582266096 | 1403 | 6 | 6 | 1 | 6 | 6 | 6 |
| 3887381369861525738 | -8585785269086934496 | 2250074648582266096 | 1403 | 6 | 6 | 1 | 6 | 6 | 6 |
| 3887381369861525738 | 6450289253524997106 | 8065311635230324086 | 14990 | 6 | 6 | 1 | 6 | 5 | 6 |
| 3887381369861525738 | -7317623190510505138 | 8065311635230324086 | 14990 | 6 | 6 | 1 | 6 | 5 | 6 |
| 3887381369861525738 | 2659909420020700610 | 8065311635230324086 | 14990 | 6 | 6 | 1 | 6 | 5 | 6 |
| 3887381369861525738 | 5980557708429672617 | 2250074648582266096 | 1403 | 6 | 6 | 1 | 6 | 6 | 6 |
| 3887381369861525738 | 9198420861261457692 | 8065311635230324086 | 14990 | 6 | 6 | 1 | 6 | 5 | 6 |
| 3887381369861525738 | 7387734859250322094 | 2250074648582266096 | 1403 | 6 | 6 | 1 | 6 | 6 | 6 |
| 3887381369861525738 | 8718371642347779580 | 2250074648582266096 | 1403 | 6 | 6 | 1 | 6 | 6 | 6 |
| 3887381369861525738 | 852611112587303935 | 2250074648582266096 | 1403 | 6 | 6 | 1 | 6 | 6 | 6 |
| 3887381369861525738 | -1388130469552469802 | 2250074648582266096 | 1403 | 6 | 6 | 1 | 6 | 6 | 6 |
| 3887381369861525738 | -1205276443672336873 | 2250074648582266096 | 1403 | 6 | 6 | 1 | 6 | 6 | 6 |
| 3887381369861525738 | 4188187389845333258 | 8065311635230324086 | 14990 | 6 | 6 | 1 | 6 | 5 | 6 |
| 3887381369861525738 | 8839304887008928323 | 8065311635230324086 | 14990 | 6 | 6 | 1 | 6 | 5 | 6 |
| 3887381369861525738 | 1165314329380729482 | 2250074648582266096 | 1403 | 6 | 6 | 1 | 6 | 6 | 6 |
| 3887381369861525738 | -2701516531203767611 | 8065311635230324086 | 14990 | 6 | 6 | 1 | 6 | 5 | 6 |
| 3887381369861525738 | 2777315403047577919 | 8065311635230324086 | 14990 | 6 | 6 | 1 | 6 | 5 | 6 |
| 3887381369861525738 | 2078952832918936688 | 2250074648582266096 | 1403 | 6 | 6 | 1 | 6 | 6 | 6 |
| 3887381369861525738 | -3599077089501770287 | 2250074648582266096 | 1403 | 6 | 6 | 1 | 6 | 6 | 6 |
| 3887381369861525738 | -5696734558259255680 | 8065311635230324086 | 14990 | 6 | 6 | 1 | 6 | 5 | 6 |
| 3887381369861525738 | -7990670065733459633 | 2250074648582266096 | 1403 | 6 | 6 | 1 | 6 | 6 | 6 |
| 3887381369861525738 | 2325956240475652770 | 8065311635230324086 | 14990 | 6 | 6 | 1 | 6 | 5 | 6 |
| 3887381369861525738 | 7738058586920141716 | 8065311635230324086 | 14990 | 6 | 6 | 1 | 6 | 5 | 6 |
| 3887381369861525738 | -7871497817898561830 | 2250074648582266096 | 1403 | 6 | 6 | 1 | 6 | 6 | 6 |
| 3887381369861525738 | -4685577508027201512 | 2250074648582266096 | 1403 | 6 | 6 | 1 | 6 | 6 | 6 |
| 3887381369861525738 | -8371413216131909451 | 2250074648582266096 | 1403 | 6 | 6 | 1 | 6 | 6 | 6 |
| 3887381369861525738 | 425185519230399127 | 8065311635230324086 | 14990 | 6 | 6 | 1 | 6 | 5 | 6 |
| 3887381369861525738 | 1945340309824620743 | 2250074648582266096 | 1403 | 6 | 6 | 1 | 6 | 6 | 6 |
| 3887381369861525738 | 2061806696474644917 | 8065311635230324086 | 14990 | 6 | 6 | 1 | 6 | 5 | 6 |
| 3887381369861525738 | 3369194188630188473 | 2250074648582266096 | 1403 | 6 | 6 | 1 | 6 | 6 | 6 |
| 3887381369861525738 | -4909645561742574038 | 8065311635230324086 | 14990 | 6 | 6 | 1 | 6 | 5 | 6 |
| 3887381369861525738 | 1688450274657701482 | 8065311635230324086 | 14990 | 6 | 6 | 1 | 6 | 5 | 6 |
| 3887381369861525738 | -7622203937653404643 | 8065311635230324086 | 14990 | 6 | 6 | 1 | 6 | 5 | 6 |
| 3887381369861525738 | 3369788839536702744 | 2250074648582266096 | 1403 | 6 | 6 | 1 | 6 | 6 | 6 |
| 3887381369861525738 | 3557755812202779741 | 2250074648582266096 | 1403 | 6 | 6 | 1 | 6 | 6 | 6 |
| 3887381369861525738 | -4616442389233058623 | 2250074648582266096 | 1403 | 6 | 6 | 1 | 6 | 6 | 6 |
| 3887381369861525738 | -2769074355108049145 | 8065311635230324086 | 14990 | 6 | 6 | 1 | 6 | 5 | 6 |
| 3887381369861525738 | -7699450308591827878 | 8065311635230324086 | 14990 | 6 | 6 | 1 | 6 | 5 | 6 |
| 3887381369861525738 | 7416677523617446771 | 8065311635230324086 | 14990 | 6 | 6 | 1 | 6 | 5 | 6 |
| 3887381369861525738 | 3103805130751933993 | 2250074648582266096 | 1403 | 6 | 6 | 1 | 6 | 6 | 6 |
| 3887381369861525738 | -4212540120345798750 | 2250074648582266096 | 1403 | 6 | 6 | 1 | 6 | 6 | 6 |
| 3887381369861525738 | 7653518056654637311 | 8065311635230324086 | 14990 | 6 | 6 | 1 | 6 | 5 | 6 |
| 3887381369861525738 | 6953418390285744175 | 2250074648582266096 | 1403 | 6 | 6 | 1 | 6 | 6 | 6 |
| 3887381369861525738 | 5406897613868013281 | 8065311635230324086 | 14990 | 6 | 6 | 1 | 6 | 5 | 6 |

Comment: You are joining from the schema in the query history to every table in the Database (Catalog) that the Schema resides in. This doesn't seem to make sense. Even if there is a valid reason for doing this, the Query History holds the Catalog Id so I'm not sure why you are going via the Schema view to get this Id?

Comment: If you are trying to identify the objects being referenced within a SQL statement (tables, views, etc), you would need to parse the QUERY_TEXT column - and this is a non-trivial task for anything but the simplest statement

Comment: @NickW Yes good point aboit that table join. I don’t know why I am doing that, it’s a mistake. However, to address the second comment doesn’t  the table_name field do that for me?

Comment: What TABLE_NAME field? There's no such field in the QUERY_HISTORY view

Comment: It comes out of the SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.tables table, which is why we are joining it against Table_Catalog_Id. The query table joins to SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.SCHEMATA, which we can then join to table catalog (that's why I was doing that).

Comment: But you've acknowledged that the join you made to TABLES doesn't make any sense and was a mistake - but then your asking why the table_name you get to via this join doesn't give you what you want? I think you need to take a step back and think in more detail about what you are doing

Comment: Well, I said that beacuse I forgot why I had it there but as I re-review the query I don't understand why it wouldn't work. That just allows me to connect from the query history table to get the list of tables that are being used in it. I'm doing all the counts against the query history table, I'm just using those joins to pull in labels - so I don't understand why it doesn't work.

Comment: The QUERY_HISTORY.SCHEMA_ID gives you the schema that was in context when the query ran. You are joining it to the SCHEMATA view that holds every schema in your account. You are then joining the catalog_id (database) of the schema to the catalog_id in the TABLES view - this view lists every table in your account. So you are picking up every table in the database that contains the schema on your query. There is no link/relationship between these tables and your query - apart from the fact they have a meaningless connection to a database

Comment: I'm confused by everything that has been stated so far in the comments.  The query is definitely not right as @NickW has pointed out.  However, why not just leverage the `ACCESS_HISTORY`??  Does that not provide you everything you need?  It literally details every object that is used for a query.  No need to parse query_text to get what you need anymore.

Comment: I didn't know about ACCESS_HISTORY, that helped. I've got a solution that works because of that. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WITH BASE AS (
SELECT
QH.ROWS_PRODUCED AS ROWS_PRODUCED,
QH.QUERY_ID AS QUERY_ID,
QH.QUERY_HASH AS QUERY_HASH,
QH.QUERY_PARAMETERIZED_HASH as QUERY_PARAMETERIZED_HASH,
QH.WAREHOUSE_NAME,
QH.QUERY_TEXT, 
QH.START_TIME, 
QH.USER_NAME,
p.value:objectName::string as ObjectName
FROM
SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.QUERY_HISTORY as QH
LEFT JOIN SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.ACCESS_HISTORY AH on AH.query_id = QH.query_id,
lateral flatten(input => ah.DIRECT_OBJECTS_ACCESSED) p
WHERE QH.QUERY_TYPE in ('SELECT') AND QH.ROWS_PRODUCED > 0 )

SELECT
 USER_NAME, ObjectName,
SUM(ROWS_PRODUCED),
COUNT(DISTINCT QUERY_ID),
COUNT(DISTINCT QUERY_HASH),
COUNT(DISTINCT QUERY_PARAMETERIZED_HASH)
FROM BASE
GROUP BY USER_NAME, ObjectName
```